# LNK1104 error for debug build in pybind11 project on visual studio with cmake & vcpkg (Windows)

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019, pybind11, vcpkg

I have created a PyBind11 project on Visual Studio using CMake & VCPkg on Windows platform. I'm exposing C++ functionality in Python.

I have *pybind11_x64-windows* & *python3.10_x64-windows* installed via *vcpkg* and *CMake3.24.1* installed through *Visual Studio 2019 Professional* separately.

I have the necessary CMakeLists.txt file in the project's root directory. The project builds correctly in **Release** mode, but in the **Debug** mode, I have linker error:

*LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python310.lib'*

I don't understand, why Visual Studio needs **python310.lib** instead of **python310_d.lib** in the **Debug** mode. In VisualStudio, when I checked the Project->Property->Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies, it correctly points to **python310_d.lib**.

I found this article on Google which seems relevant to some extent:

https://discourse.paraview.org/t/debug-build-fail-cannot-open-file-python310-lib/9000

but there doesn't seem to be a clear solution.

Is this a bug in VCPkg/CMake/Python or something else ? Does anyone have a solution to this ?